# How to send notification from iPhone to apple watch?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, apple-watch, watchos-2

I want to send notification from iOS App to the apple watch app.

I will receive push notification on iPhone. When I receive the push notification I want to send a notification to my apple watch app along with some data like name,time, and just plain text. I am new to the apple watch. I have seen an example **MMWormable**, but that does not send notifications. It sends only data from iOS App when both the apps are running, but i want to send notification even if app is closed on both the iPhone & Apple watch.

EDIT:
I have read https://support.apple.com/en-in/HT204791 it says it will show notifications to apple watch when if iPhone is locked & it will not show notifications on apple watch if iPhone is not locked.

How can i show notifications to both the iPhone & apple watch.

Comment: why there is a downvote ???????

Comment: You need to study more about the interaction between Apple Watch and iOS App. The question is way too broad and can't be answered on StackOverFlow.

Comment: Not broad i am just asking when  push or local notification arrives on iPhone then i want to pass data of notification to Apple watch

Answer (score 1):

for the solution, if you use a simulator, you have to turn off the simulator with the power button according to the device, later the notification will enter the apple watch automatically

Answer (score 0):

If push or local notification arrives on iPhone it will display notification only on iPhone[if the phone is unlocked].If it is locked notification will be displayed on watch. FYI notification wont be displayed on both ,OS will choose device in which user is active.

Answer (score 0):

If you want than you can add it on local notification an also on watch to fetch the data.